# Numeric string extraction after expression

Tags: r, regex, string

Hi I have this sting in a Dataframe (column is named value)

```
Laboratory <- as_tibble("Hematologie: Leukocyty  [WBC]: 11.0 [10^9/l] ,Erytrocyty  [RBC]: 5.19 [10^12/l], Hemoglobin  [HGB]: 167 [g/l] ,Hematokrit  [HCT]: 0.465 [1], Bio: | Urea: 3.6 | Creatinin: 87 | Sodium: 145")
```

And I would like to get a table where columns will be values of WBC, Bio and Urea

```
DF Laboratory

 WBC  Bio  Urea
 11.0 NA   3.6
```

I try this

```
Laboratory %>%
 mutate(WBC = str_extract(value,"(?<=[WBC]:).+(?=[10^9/l]"),
 Bio = str_extract(value,"(?<=Bio:).+(?=\\|"), 
 Urea = str_extract(value,"(?<=Urea:).+(?=\\|"))
```

But there is an error

```
Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
Laboratory %>%
 mutate(WBC = trimws(str_extract(value,"(?<=\\[WBC]:\\s)[^\\[]+")),
 Bio = str_extract(value,"(?<=Bio:\\s)[^\\s|]+"), 
 Urea = str_extract(value,"(?<=Urea:\\s)[^|\\s]+")
)
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=\\[WBC]:\\s)[^\\[]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnpvOw/1)) - matches one or more chars other than `[` after `[WBC]:` and a whitespace (`trimws` removes leading/trailing whitespace)
- `(?<=Bio:\s)[^\s|]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnpvOw/2)) - matches one or more chars other than whitespace and `|` after `Bio:` and a whitespace
- `(?<=Urea:\s)[^|\s]+` - similar to the pattern above, just woth `Urea:` string.

In the last two patterns, you can drop the `\s` inside the lookbehind (`(?<=Bio:\\s)` -> `(?<=Bio:)`) and from the negated character class, but you will need to `trimws` the resulting match value as in the first case with `WBC`.